# Send data from socket to another socket

Tags: python, sockets, twisted

The code below receives data through sockets from an iPhone, and then I want to send that received data to another python script running through a different socket. My attempt is below. The other server receives the message fine however I am getting an errno 9 bad file descriptor as soon as I send the **second** message. Is there anyway to change the below code so it can continuously  send received data straight to another socket?

```
import os
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory
from twisted.internet import reactor
from threading import Thread



class IphoneChat(Protocol):


    def connectionMade(self):
        self.factory.clients.append(self)
        print "A new client has connected"

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print "client disconnected"

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print "Message Received: ", data
        TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
        TCP_PORT = 5000
        BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
        s.send(data)
        s.close()




    def message(self, message):
        self.transport.write(message + '\n')



factory = Factory()
factory.protocol = IphoneChat
factory.clients = []



reactor.listenTCP(3000, factory)
print "listening to 3000"

reactor.run()
```

Comment: Please fix the code or fill the missing part.... It cannot work or `s` is a global variable in `dataReceived()` method: that will raise your error.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of errors in your `IphoneChat` code: a missing `import socket` and `self.s = socket.socket(...)` should just bind to a local variable `s`, not to the instance variable `self.s`.

Nevertheless, I think that the exception (`socket.error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor`) is actually being raised in the "other" Python script for which you don't show any code. It would be helpful to see that code, however, it is likely that you are closing the *main server socket* in response to the connection being closed by the `IphoneChat` script, rather than the *per connection socket* returned by `socket.accept()`. Here's some rough code that should work as the receiving server:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 5000))
s.listen(1)

while True:
    print "Waiting for connection... ",
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print "Got connection from {}".format(addr)
    while True:
        msg = conn.recv(1024)
        if msg == '':
            print "Remote disconnected"
            break
        print "Got msg: %r" % msg

    # N.B. close connection to remote peer, not the main server socket "s"
    conn.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
    conn.close()
```

My guess is that you have code similar to the above, but that you are closing the main server socket instead of the remote connection.